# Who vs whom in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Which of the two sentences is correct?

*Everybody **who** we need* or *Everybody **whom** we need*

Please explain the grammatical reason behind it.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you assume (a) that one of them is correct? and (b) that only one of them is correct? and (c) that there are only two possibilities?

Comment: The two sentences are both correct. But I suspect that's not what OP is really asking about.

Answer (score 0):

First, as presented, neither is a sentence, and without the completed sentence it is impossible to know which, if either, is the correct answer.

Depending, of course, on the rest of the sentence, I'm inclined to propose that a better option than either of the choices presented is to delete the who/whom, and simply write "Everyone we need..."

Comment: No, under the traditional English grammar rules, which I think are still the most generally acceptable, the question has all the relevant information. The case of a relative pronoun is determined only by its function in the relative clause. Since the relative clause is "who[m] we need", not "who needs us", the objective case is required, not the nominative case. The objective case was once *whom*, but nowadays it is always fully acceptable to replace it by *who*. (Exception: fixed idioms such as "to whom it may concern".) So *who* is always correct, and in this case *whom* is also correct.

Comment: Some English speakers have broken with tradition and select the case of *who[m]* according to its function in the main clause. These speakers can't tell without additional information whether *whom* is allowed in this sentence. (Ironically some of these progressive speakers even subscribe to the conservative idea that *whom* may never be replaced by *who*.) But these speakers are still in a minority, and in any case such a new development doesn't immediately invalidate what has been correct for centuries.